# Ruby: What is the speed difference between While and Until loops?

Tags: ruby

I'm learning Ruby right now. Coming from using Javascript the past couple of years, I'm familiar with the While loop. But the until loop? I've looked around but couldn't find a solid reason why one would be better than the other.

Ruby has "until" which is described as another way to phrase a problem. The way I see it, "while" iterates until false, and "until" iterates until true.

I'm sure that most of the programs I write won't really need refactoring for speed. However, I like to get into the little details sometimes.

Is there a speed difference between the two loops? Why is there an "until" syntax in Ruby? Why not just stick with "while?"

Comment: Related (not dupe): https://stackoverflow.com/q/45069756/525478

Comment: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There would not be a speed difference between `while` and `until` as they mirror each other.

We'll compare a `while` loop with an `until` loop:

```
n = 0
puts n += 1 while n != 3

n = 0
puts n += 1 until n == 3
```

These will both print 1 through 3.

Here's a diff between the two disassembled human-readable instruction sequences from the Ruby VM:

```
@@ -13,7 +13,7 @@
 0021 pop              
 0022 getlocal_OP__WC__0 2
 0024 putobject        3
-0026 opt_neq          <callinfo!mid:!=, argc:1, ARGS_SIMPLE>, <callcache>, <callinfo!mid:==, argc:1, ARGS_SIMPLE>, <callcache>
-0031 branchif         8
-0033 putnil           
-0034 leave
+0026 opt_eq           <callinfo!mid:==, argc:1, ARGS_SIMPLE>, <callcache>
+0029 branchunless     8
+0031 putnil           
+0032 leave
```

A `while` loop uses a `branchif` for its jump, whereas the `until` loop used a `branchunless`. So, these loops simply differ in the comparison being made, which you can see by looking at how `branchif` and `branchunless` are [defined](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_2_4/insns.def#L1186):

```c
DEFINE_INSN
branchif
(OFFSET dst)
(VALUE val)
()
{
    if (RTEST(val)) {
    RUBY_VM_CHECK_INTS(th);
    JUMP(dst);
    }
}
```

```c
DEFINE_INSN
branchunless
(OFFSET dst)
(VALUE val)
()
{
    if (!RTEST(val)) {
    RUBY_VM_CHECK_INTS(th);
    JUMP(dst);
    }
}
```

Performance between `while` and `until` should be nearly identical. Usage should be determined by readability.

Comment: Wow, this is actually really cool to see! Thank you. Where can I learn more about this?

Comment: @Nathan There's a great book about Ruby's internals: [_Ruby Under a Microscope_](https://www.nostarch.com/rum) by Pat Shaughnessy. Pat has some excerpts in a few blog posts here: http://patshaughnessy.net/2012/6/29/how-ruby-executes-your-code There aren't too many resources about this topic. There are a few blog posts, but they tend to reference Pat's book.

Comment: Note: Ruby Under a Microscope is *not* a book about Ruby's internals. It is a book about YARV's internals. (Ruby is a programming language, a language is a specification, a piece of paper, it has no "internals".) As far as I know, it doesn't cover TruffleRuby *at all*, for example, which I personally think is by far the most interesting Ruby implementation to study.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Right! The book specifically looks at YARV/MRI, but it's a great source for those looking to learn more. If you know of other resources for those looking to learn, please share. TruffleRuby is a very interesting implementation which stands out among other implementations. I'm just waiting for MRI's [deoptimizations](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/pull/1419)... :)

Comment: FWIW, it looks like Ruby Under a Microscope spends a chapter each on JRuby and Rubinius. Both Ruby Under a Microscope and TruffleRuby look pretty interesting, I guess I have some reading to do...

Answer (score 3):

Speed differences aside, it's really all about readability, which is something that Ruby prides itself on.

Let's pretend we're making a drink - which do you think reads better?

```
A) pour_drink until glass.full?
B) pour_drink while !glass.full?
```

Comment: Ok, yeah, I get that. the [until] statement is more readable. 

But really, the question is about speed. In a large program, would it really make a difference? How much of "until" is being parsed down into machine code compared to "while"?

Comment: @Nathan: "I'm learning Ruby right now." - In this case, worrying about what bytecode gets generated should be the __last__ thing on your mind. Ruby programs are never slow just because one loop keyword is "slower" than the other.

Answer (score 3):

Speed will be more influenced by your choice of comparison operator than your choice of `while` or `until`

```
Benchmark.bmbm do |bm|
  bm.report('while') do
    n = 0
    n += 1 while n != 10_000_000
  end

  bm.report('until') do
    n = 0
    n += 1 until n == 10_000_000
  end
end

            user     system      total        real
while   0.250000   0.000000   0.250000 (  0.247949)
until   0.220000   0.000000   0.220000 (  0.222049)
```

With `while n != 10_000_000` vs. `until n == 10_000_000`, `until` appears to be faster.

```
Benchmark.bmbm do |bm|
  bm.report('while') do
    n = 0
    n += 1 while n < 10_000_000
  end

  bm.report('until') do
    n = 0
    n += 1 until n == 10_000_000
  end
end

            user     system      total        real
while   0.210000   0.000000   0.210000 (  0.207265)
until   0.220000   0.000000   0.220000 (  0.223195)
```

Change it to `while n < 10_000_000` and now `while` seems to have the edge. To be fair we should give them the more equivalent `while n < 10_000_000` vs. `until n > 9_999_999`

```
Benchmark.bmbm do |bm|
  bm.report('while') do
    n = 0
    n += 1 while n < 10_000_000
  end

  bm.report('until') do
    n = 0
    n += 1 until n > 9_999_999
  end
end

            user     system      total        real
while   0.200000   0.000000   0.200000 (  0.208428)
until   0.200000   0.000000   0.200000 (  0.206218)
```

Now they're almost identical. So follow Ruby's lead and gain your satisfaction from code that reads like an English sentence. But make sure you use `<` or `>` to gain that extra boost of .0000000001 seconds.

Comment: This is kinda cool, but yeah, I can see where speed is a very negligible difference here. Obviously this will also depend on each individual computer at this level. Thank you for the effort on writing this up for me.

Comment: @Nathan No problem! Thanks for asking the question. Jon's answer is definitely better at explaining why they're the same, there's no way I could top that. But it's always fun to write up some benchmarks and test things out for real.

Comment: @Nathan It was interesting to see that `!=` was about 20% slower than `<` in this context